# Dynamically create properties from yaml

Tags: java, spring

I have a yaml configuration as follows:

```
templates:
  - name: demoTemplate
    id: demo-template-id
    commands:
      - name: createFolder
        someCommandProperty: aValue
        anotherCommandProperty: aSecondValue
      - name: createUser
        yetAnotherProperty: aValue
        andAnotherYetProperty: aSecondValue
```

I have a class `TemplateCommandConfigDTO` that looks as follows:

```
public class TemplateCommandConfigDTO{

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

How do i grab the other property fields dynamically and put them in the template command config dto without having to explicitly say `private string someCommandProperty` for instance.

Does this make sense?

UPDATE:

My current solution i'm working on is something like this...

```
public class TemplateCommandConfigPropertyDTO {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    public String getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(String key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And configuration

```
templates:
  - name: demoTemplate
    id: demo-template-id
    commands:
      - name: createFolder
        properties:
          someCommandProperty: aValue
          anotherCommandProperty: aSecondValue
```

And class:

```
public class TemplateCommandConfigDTO{

    private String name;
    private Set<TemplateCommandConfigPropertyDTO> properties;

    public Set<TemplateCommandConfigPropertyDTO> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    public void setProperties(Set<TemplateCommandConfigPropertyDTO> properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could deserialise the whole thing into a `Map<String, ?>` and then `someCommandProperty` would be somewhere in that tree...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko can you provide a solution i could look at? im still fairly new here to java

Comment: `new com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper(new com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.yaml.YAMLFactory())` - that's where you could start. Read about Jackson API and their support for YAML. `reader.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {})`